# Selenium Grid opening dozens of Chrome instances

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have an interesting issue that I have searched the Selenium bug log and stack overflow for, but have not come across anyone else who has had this similar issue.

I am running my Selenium C# test suite via NUnit3 Console Runner across 6 VM Selenium nodes. I have roughly 400 tests in our suite and have configured each node to only run 4 tests concurrently at any given time. Sometimes it executes completely without issue, and then other times I will go into the VM and see that dozens of Chrome instances have opened up, choking out resources and killing my execution. These instances freeze up and are not disposed of by Grid, so I have to manually kill the processes.

When I run a command to kill chrome.exe, I will sometimes see 50+ instances of Chrome being killed. My first thought was Chrome was not being properly disposed of at the end of each test run, and I played around with `driver.Dispose()` as well as `driver.Close(); driver.Quit();`. This did not rectify the issue.

I then attempted the following with no avail:

- Updating the versions of chromedriver, chrome, selenium server, selenium webdriver, and nunit --> I have attempted variations of compatible versions of each, but the issue persists across the different versions.
- Reducing the number of concurrent sessions per VM (changing the NUnit console switch `--workers=12` (this way only 2 browser instances per VM are executed at any given time -- typically we use `--workers=24` to run 4 browsers per VM simultaneously). Our VMs should be able to handle 4 browser instances at once, however.
- Creating JSON node and hub configurations, setting `"timeout": 120` at the hub level and `"maxInstances": 4` and `"maxSessions": 4` at the node level.

Below are the current versions used in our execution:

- Selenium Webdriver v3.9.1
- Selenium Standalone Server v3.6.0
- Chromedriver v2.33.0
- Chrome v62.0.3202.75
- NUnit v3.9.0
- NUnit ConsoleRunner v3.8.0

Below is additional details on how our tests are run:

- We have a SetupTeardown class that is extended in each test class. The `[TestFixture]` attribute is at the SetupTeardown class level.
- `[TearDown]` method will dispose of the driver in a `try/catch/finally` block to ensure the `.Dispose()` method is always called.
- All tests are adorned with the `[Parallelizable]` attribute.
- Selenium Server Standalone, chromedriver, and batch files to start the nodes/hub are on a shared drive and the shared files are called by each node.

I have been wracking my brain for weeks trying to find a root cause and have had no luck whatsoever. Is there an additional configuration I need to set on the grid hub to take care of the frozen instances and dispose of them as they become unresponsive? I am confusing the grid by setting the `--workers` attribute in the NUnit3 Console Runner command? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the terminology you are using, but if you run on six different instances of nunit3-console with `--workers=24`, that will give you 144 test threads!

Comment: @Charlie Sorry, just to clarify we are running 6 VMs and one instance of nunit3-console from a remote machine that pushes the tests out to each of the 6 VMs in the grid :)

Comment: Does each VM have a separate instance of a test assembly + nunit.framework? If so, each one gets 24 (or 12) workers. However, this is from an NUnit perspective, not Selenium (which may modify it).

Comment: @Charlie They do not - Just the hub machine contains the test assembly and nunit framework.

Comment: I see. I just read up on it and I see that the architecture isn't what I had assumed. Interesting.

Comment: Is your SetUpTearDown class abstract? It should be if it isn't, unless you move the TestFixture attribute to each individual class -the latter is what I prefer for clarity. Otherwise, NUnit will try to run the base class as a fixture __by itself__.

Comment: @Charlie That's correct, the SetUpTearDown class is abstract, and that is where I have the TestFixture attribute. Then each test inherits the SetUpTearDown class. Is it best practice for each test to be adorned with the TestFixture attribute instead?

Comment: Both approaches work equally well for NUnit. I personally consider putting the attribute (if used) on the derived classes a better approach, because it puts the info where needed. Of course, TestFixture is actually optional unless the fixture has arguments or Type parameters.

Comment: BTW I'm not following up with an answer because this seems to be a problem with using the Selenium grid rather than with NUnit. Outside of my expertise. :-)